# Como saber se o pwa já foi instalado em outro domínio?

Tags: javascript, pwa

Tenho uma mesma aplicação rodando em 2 domínios diferentes, uma é `examplo.com` e a outra `exemplo2.com`

Nessa aplicação tem um botão em que o usuário pode clicar para fazer o download da aplicação, esse botão desaparece quando o usuário realiza o download. Porém se eu acessar a mesma aplicação em um domínio diferente, o botão continua lá

Como resolver?

```
const buttonAddToHomeScreen = document.querySelector('#addToHomeScreen');

let deferredPrompt;

window.on('beforeinstallprompt', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    deferredPrompt = event;

    buttonAddToHomeScreen.style.display = 'block';
    buttonAddToHomeScreen.style.opacity = '1';
});

buttonAddToHomeScreen.on('click', function() {
    if (!deferredPrompt) return;

    deferredPrompt.prompt();

    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(function() {
        buttonAddToHomeScreen.style.display = 'none';
        buttonAddToHomeScreen.style.opacity = '0';

        deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um cookie pra verificar se o botão já foi clicado e setar esse cookie em ambos os domínios com a ajuda de um iframe (uma vez que o cookie é único por domínio).

Ou seja, você pode criar uma página "setcookie" com o script abaixo e coloca-lá na rota `examplo.com/setcookie` e `examplo2.com/setcookie`

```js
localStorage.setItem('botaoClicado', 'true')
```

e depois alterar a lógica de visualização do botão para só mostrar caso `localStorage.getItem('botaoClicado')` não seja `null`.

Para setar o cookie basta carregar os dois iframes na sua página após o usuário clicar no botão de download (ou pode colocar na página de "agradecimento do download" caso haja). Uma alternativa para fazer isso é a seguinte:

```js
function aoClicarEmDownload(){
let body = document.getElementByTagName('body')[0]
let iframe1 = document.createElement("iframe")
iframe1.src = "http://exemplo.com/setcookie"
iframe1.height = "0"
iframe1.width = "0"
body.appendChild(iframe1)

let iframe2 = document.createElement("iframe")
iframe2.src = "http://exemplo.com/setcookie"
iframe2.height = "0"
iframe2.width = "0"
body.appendChild(iframe2)
}
```